# Check the Key of JSON

Tags: javascript, json

```
var x = {
    "completed": "",
    "globalExposures": "10",
    "tagExposures": [
        {"8": 11},{"5": 12},{"10":23}      
    ]
};
```

I want to access the Keys of "tagExposures" i.e. 8, 5 and 10 using JSON. I want to perform operation if specific key is present.  I tried below code, but it doesn't give desired o/p. Please, Suggest.

```
var exp = {
    "completed": "",
    "globalExposures": "10",
    "tagExposures": [
        {"8": 11},{"5": 12} ,{"10":23}      
    ]
};
var arr=exp["tagExposures"];
var kys=[];
for(k in arr){
  if(arr.hasOwnProperty(k)) kys.push(k);
}
console.log(kys); //=> This gives ['0','1']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misdefined the `tagExposures` associative array.  This gives "8, 5" for example:

```
var exp = {
    "completed": "",
    "globalExposures": "10",
    "tagExposures": {
        "8": 11,"5": 12
    }
};
var arr=exp["tagExposures"];
var kys=[];
for(k in arr){
  if(arr.hasOwnProperty(k)) kys.push(k);
}
console.log(kys);
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because `tagExposures` is an array with keys 0 and 1

```
"tagExposures": [
        {"8": 11},// 0
        {"5": 12} // 1      
    ]
```

If you try your same code with `tagExposures` looking like this:

```
"tagExposures": {
        "8": 11,
        "5": 12      
    }
```

It would work as you wanted.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/H5z6N/

Output: `["5", "8"]`

Comment: Thanks Neal for quick reply! Do you have any idea to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(k in arr){
  if(arr.hasOwnProperty(k)) kys.push(k);
}
```

is wrong for arrays. Just use a normal loop in combination with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), which returns the keys of each object (which is one key each time):

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    kys = kys.concat(Object.keys(arr[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for(k in arr)` loop is giving you the keys from `tagExposures`, which is an array.  You need another for loop to get the keys from the objects.

```
for(k in arr){
    if(arr.hasOwnProperty(k)){
        var obj = arr[k];
        for(v in obj){
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(v)){
                kys.push(v);
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(kys); // ["8", "5", "10"]
```